# How to replace "template <typename ..." with a macro?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c-preprocessor, boilerplate

With what macro can I replace the "template..." boilerplate with something shorter?
ie: instead of these:

```
template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
/*constructor*/ GraphDirected::
GraphDirected()
{
}
template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
/*destructor*/ GraphDirected::
~GraphDirected()
{
    clear();
}    
template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
void GraphDirected::
clear()
{
    nodes.clear();
    arcs.clear();
}
```

I want to write this:

```
boilerplate(/*constructor*/)
GraphDirected()
{
}
boilerplate(/*destructor*/)
~GraphDirected()
{
    clear();
}
boilerplate(void)
clear()
{
    nodes.clear();
    arcs.clear();
}
```

And of course at the end I would need some protection (? #undef ?) so that other files not get messed up.

If it isnt much more complicated, how could uglynesses like these be handled?:

```
template <typename ElemType>
typename BST<ElemType>::nodeT * BST<ElemType>::
recFindNode(nodeT *t, ElemType & key) { ... }
```

Comment: At first I was afraid somebody wanted a macro for *just* the three tokens `template <typename`.

Comment: Why not defining these methods right inside the class definition?

Comment: @ipc: Exactly my thought!

Comment: @ipc: they would all be inlined

Comment: those are just example methods

Comment: template functions are *always* inline.

Comment: @ipc: not exactly, the types are substituted and then compiled, which is not the same as inlining, (btw: recursive functions cannot  be inlined, since you do not know the depth of recursion at compile time)

Comment: @ipc: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5431498/185819

Comment: @DarkFalcon: This is exactly what I said.

Comment: What problems are you having? This should be doable (although nobody would recommend it) without any advanced incantations - it's a simple text substitution.

Comment: @ipc: No it is not. You said that they are always inlined. That is not what that post says. Inlining and templates are not directly related.

Comment: I said they are always inline (!= always inlined). Whether they are inlined or not cannot be influenced.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: just let him be wrong

Answer (score 3):

I would not suggest you to use MACRO just to avoid few tokens. Since the definition of members of a class template has to be in the same file, you have to define them in the same file, even if you do that outside the class.

A better solution is to *define* the members *inside the class itself*, so you don't have to repeat the tokens everytime you define a member.

Remember that templates generate ugly error messages, and MACRO is EVIL. If you combine both, you will see even uglier and insane error messages when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

well, I see nothing wrong if you can beautify your template boilerplate by:

```
#define pretty ugly
```

as long as you feel it does no harm.

For types, you can always do a typedef

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't like typing, you could replace `typename` with `class`, use standardized template names for your application domain, and write `struct` instead of `class` to avoid typing `public:`, and finally make the class header-only:

```
template <class N, class A>
struct GraphDirected
{
    GraphDirected() {} // default constructor
    // rest of the class definition

private:
    // helpers and data go here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ preprocessor has very little knowledge about the code it is working on.
As such, you would need to `#define` the terms you wanted to use.

However, something like:

```
template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
/*constructor*/ GraphDirected::
GraphDirected()
{
}
template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
/*destructor*/ GraphDirected::
~GraphDirected()
{
    clear();
}    
template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
void GraphDirected::
clear()
{
    nodes.clear();
    arcs.clear();
}
```

Could easly be rewritten with this in some header:

```
#define boilerplate(rType) boilerplate_template rType boilerplate_class::
```

And then at the top of the class definition:

```
#define boilerplate_class GraphDirected
#define boilerplate_template template <typename NodeDataT, typename ArcDataT>
```

So then you could use:

```
boilerplate(/*constructor*/)
GraphDirected()
{
}
boilerplate(/*destructor*/)
~GraphDirected()
{
    clear();
}
boilerplate(void)
clear()
{
    nodes.clear();
    arcs.clear();
}
```

**Note:** As others have noted, this is a bad idea.
For such a simple case as the example the two `#define`s at the top of the file will explain the code to anybody trying to maintain it. However, be warned that this can rapidly result in unreadable and unmaintainable code. A better solution is to use an editor that can both complete these for you and fold them away so you can't see them. That way the actual file remains in a more standard format for the next time they are edited (be it by you or another).